# Send/receive paradigm in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This is the scenario, with two layers(objects) in the picture:

Layer 0 : network, Layer 1 : processor. The processor can send events to the external world via the network object. On the reverse side, the network object forwards the events received from the 
external world to the processor object.

This is a basic flow in C/C++, have implemented this several times:

- Network object exposes a send API
- It also exposes an API to register a receive handler. The processor would use this to install it's processing method, etc.

Along with an unregister interface to cleanly tear down things.

But this looks pretty messy to do in Rust, because of the lifetime checks and other reasons. For example, creating a closure that captures &mut self is not feasible. I have some round about ways in mind(like stuffing things in `Arc<Mutex<..>>`, using message queues between the objects, etc). What is the best/cleanest way of doing this in Rust?

Thanks.

Comment: This is quite a bit broader than the stackoverflow rules allow; the choice of tools depends on how and where you decide to structure stuff, and as such, there isn't one "generic" response to this, sadly. In some cases, a futures-aware `RwLock` comes in handy, for example. Due to this vagueness, I'll have to vote to close this question.

Comment: Lifetimes, broadly speaking, let you do stuff in Rust that you just *can't do* in C++, such as putting references in `struct`s. They don't usually inhibit translating a design concept-for-concept (although the lack of class-based inheritance may). For example, C++ doesn't have `&mut` references, only shared references, so there's no reason you would *need* to capture a `&mut` reference in a closure when translating a C++ design. Whether or not it's a good idea to translate a C++ design into Rust, well, it probably depends on the specifics.

Comment: @trentcl Even if that is the case, the moment you've got threads into the picture you're going to need data access constraints, the same way Rust does. The problem is the same in C, it's just that C allows you to shoot yourself in the foot faster and more often.